# Phone Auth Credential

Tags: java, android, android-intent, firebase-authentication

I'm working with PhoneAuthCredential which is working fine but I need to check if user-provided some data like username and email before redirecting him to home activity and if I didn't find this data I have to redirect him to registering activity so I can get this data before logging him in

```
public class VerifyPhoneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String verificationId;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    DatabaseReference users;


    ProgressBar progressBar;
    TextInputEditText editText;
    AppCompatButton buttonSignIn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_phone);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextCode);
        buttonSignIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);

        String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phoneNumber");
        sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);

        // save phone number
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("USER_PREF",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
        editor.apply();

        buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String code = editText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (code.isEmpty() || code.length() < 6) {

                    editText.setError("Enter code...");
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        });

    }

    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
        signInWithCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            if(user!=null){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, DriverHome.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                number,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
                mCallBack
        );

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            mCallBack = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            verificationId = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            if (code != null) {
                editText.setText(code);
                verifyCode(code);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not much clear. From which activity do you hope to get this information?

Create an activity to get the user's information. 
Ex:- `UserInformationActivity`

In the java file you can create a firebase database node to store this information

Database Reference:

```
DatabaseReference userinfo=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Info").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCureentUser().getUid());
```

Use a `Hashmap` to insert the data into the node.

```
Hashmap hash = new Hashmap();
hash.put("Username", username);
hash.put("Email", email);
userinfo.updateChildren(hash);
```

And in your `VerifyPhoneActivity` class, when you successfully authenticated the user, check if the datasnapshot of that reference exists in the firebase database. Update your code in `VerifyPhoneActivity` class like this:

```
final DatabaseReference us=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User Info").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser.getUid())
```

And update your signInwithCredential() method like this:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if(user!=null){
    us.addValueEventlistner(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, DriverHome.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish(); }
            else{
                Intent gotoUserInfo=new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this,UserInformationActivity.class);
                startActivity(gotoUserInfo);
                finish();
            } }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Hope this will help. Thank you!

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work, let me explain what exactly I want, I want to create Phone Auth Credential like Uber, I mean when user use the app for the first time he has to complete his registration information after phone authentication then he will be able to move to DriverHome Activity, but next time he uses the authentication he will redirect to the DriverHome Activity automatically.